# animating round progress bars in jquery with numbers 0-10+decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, progress-bar

please bear with me as i'm fairly new to jquery & js in general...

Here's what i have so far. http://jsfiddle.net/hqwxogqt/1/

```
$(function(){
    var $ppc = $('.progress'),
        percent = parseInt($ppc.data('percent')),
        deg = 360*percent/5;
    if (percent > 2.5) {
        $ppc.addClass('gt-50');
    }
    $('.ss-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
    $('.ss-percent span').html(percent);
});
```

I actually found this somewhere & was able to implement it but i don't know how to animate it.

the animation i want to do is similar to how to the round counter (counts from 1-10) works here: awwwards.com

basically just to have it move from 0 to the certain number obtained from the div element. the number needs to only be from 0-5 & i also want to include decimals to the count but i can't figure out how.

i tried using a while loop & anything i found online doesn't seem to work probably because i have no clue how to use it or it's just not applicable to what i want to do. i'm just out of options...
any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You use parseInt so you are going to lose the decimal places. Change to parseFloat and you are half way there.

Comment: thanks! i didn't knew that. only thing left now is perhaps how would i animate it so it'd move from 0 to _italic_data-percent_italic_'s value...

Comment: This might inspire you: http://jsfiddle.net/andsens/mLA7X/ along with the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@andsens/radial-progress-indicator-using-css-a917b80c43f9)

Comment: hey this is nice @JeffNoel thanks! i was actually looking for ways to add effects & delays to the answer i got. hehe. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic idea: If you want them to animate for a set time, calculate the step size so it is dynamic.

```js
function updatePercentage () {
    
    var elem = $(this);
    var current = elem.data("percent-current") || 0;
    
    var percent = parseFloat(current) + .1;
    var max = parseFloat(elem.data("percent"));
    if (percent > max) {
        percent = max;   
    }
    
    percent = percent.toFixed(1);
    
    deg = 360*percent/5;
    
    elem.data("percent-current", percent);
    
    elem.toggleClass('gt-50', percent > 2.5);
    
    elem.find('.ss-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)'); 
    elem.find('.ss-percent span').html(percent);
    if (percent != max) {
        window.setTimeout( updatePercentage.bind(this), 100);        
    }
}


$(function(){
 var $ppc = $('.progress');
    $ppc.each(updatePercentage);    
});
```

```css
.progress {width: 200px; height: 200px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #E5E5E5; position: relative;}
.progress.gt-50 {background-color: #81CE97;}
.ss-progress {content: ""; position: absolute; border-radius: 50%; left: calc(50% - 100px); top: calc(50% - 100px); width: 200px; height: 200px; clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 100px);}
.ss-progress .ss-progress-fill { content: ""; position: absolute; border-radius: 50%; left: calc(50% - 100px); top: calc(50% - 100px);
 width: 200px; height: 200px; clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0); background: #81CE97; transform: rotate(60deg);}
.gt-50 .ss-progress {clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);}
.gt-50 .ss-progress .ss-progress-fill {clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 100px); background: #E5E5E5;}
.ss-percent {content: ""; position: absolute; border-radius: 50%; left: calc(50% - 173.91304px/2); top: calc(50% - 173.91304px/2);
 width: 173.91304px; height: 173.91304px; background: #fff; text-align: center; display: table;}
.ss-percent span {display: block; font-size: 2.6em; font-weight: bold; color: #81CE97;}
.ss-percent-wrapper {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress" data-percent="1">
 <div class="ss-progress">
  <div class="ss-progress-fill"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="ss-percent">
  <div class="ss-percent-wrapper">
   <span>%</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="progress" data-percent="2.5">
 <div class="ss-progress">
  <div class="ss-progress-fill"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="ss-percent">
  <div class="ss-percent-wrapper">
   <span>%</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="progress" data-percent="3">
 <div class="ss-progress">
  <div class="ss-progress-fill"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="ss-percent">
  <div class="ss-percent-wrapper">
   <span>%</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="progress" data-percent="5">
 <div class="ss-progress">
  <div class="ss-progress-fill"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="ss-percent">
  <div class="ss-percent-wrapper">
   <span>%</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! exactly what i needed. hehe. =) i'm still trying to wrap my head around the code thinking how it worked. but i'll understand it once i take a deeper look into it. thanks man!